# R610 SAS6 Raid 1 Not Recognizing Replacement Drive

Tags: dell, hardware-raid, raid1

I have a Dell R610 with a SAS 6 controller. There's 2 drives (slot 0 and 1) setup in a raid 1. The drive in slot 0 failed and was replaced. However when I installed it (slot 0), the SAS6 controller is not detecting the new drive (and thus still in a degraded state). I tried to configure it via the ctrl-c text based configuration utility. I plugged the replacement drive in another host and confirmed it works. Any thoughts on what else I can do? The drive is same make/model as the dead drive. Host is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Was the replacement drive an official Dell replacement with the correct FRU# ?

Comment: The replacement done through warranty with WD. Exact Make/Model as the dead drive.

Comment: OK, this here sounds along the same lines as your issue, maybe it will help: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/t/19523824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Disk 0 wasn't getting enumerated. I moved the replacement drive from Slot 0 to slot 3 and it finally recognized the new drive.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the drive is clear and not initialised (GPT/MBR etc) otherwise the raid card can interpret this as a 'foreign' HDD and not automatically import it to avoid destroying any data on it that you may want to use to recreate a foreign raid array.

Another thing I found on older Dells is adding the drive while the server is powered down doesn't always trigger the import of the drive into the existing virtual disk, it helped to plug in the drive while the server was running, while outside of the raid controllers interface.

Hope this helps.